# Using Oracle Driver in TSQLConnection

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I am using Delphi XE2 and dbExpress in my application. While developing I come to know that I need to install SQL Native client to use MSSQL as driver in dbExpress connection setup (as client machine don’t have SQL installed on it)

Could you please let me know which client I need to install if I want to use Oracle as a Driver in dbExpress (as client machine don’t have any Oracle component installed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the Oracle Client corresponding to the bitness of your application.

For XE2, if your application is 64 bit, you need the x64 client.

If your application is 32 bit, you need the x86 client.

Installing the *Oracle Client* is a huge process - `win32_11gR2_client.zip` is around 700 MB - not bad just for a client! During installation, for DBExpress to work, you just need to select the OCI libraries, not ODBC nor OleDB providers, nor JDBC (unless other Java or .Net clients expect them).

You can install the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html), which is a set of OCI libraries files - here . Get the latest version, even if your server is older. But there is not installer: you have to uncompress them in your path, or in the executable folder. If you put it in the path, be aware that it may break any installation of other "full clients".  The *Instant Client Package - Basic Lite*: is the smallest (20 MB), works very well, but only with English error messages and Unicode, ASCII, and Western European character set support.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Instantclient is sufficient.

Comment: But you have to let the .dll be in your path, since OCI does not have any setup, but just some plain .dll files.